# Show default background in ProgressBar Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to set default background in `ProgressBar` which is different from the background we set programmatically.
For i.e. Check image shown below, Its progress is very less and so user is not able to see progress data which is written on it. So I want default any color background behind each progress bar like image shown below it.

[image: progress bar]

[image]

**Code :**

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aaReportData,
                    R.layout.report_card1, new String[] { "Topic", "Accuracy",
                            "Accuracy1" }, new int[] { R.id.tvTopic,
                            R.id.pbTopicAccuracy, R.id.tvAccuracy });

            adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

                @Override
                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                        String textRepresentation) {
                    if (view.getId() == R.id.pbTopicAccuracy) {
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(data.toString());
                        ((ProgressBar) view).setProgress(value);

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                value, 30);
                        params.leftMargin = 185;
                        params.topMargin = 3;
                        ((ProgressBar) view).setLayoutParams(params);

                        if (value >= 0 && value <= 10) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_010));
                        }
                        if (value > 10 && value <= 20) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_1020));
                        }
                        if (value > 20 && value <= 30) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_2030));
                        } else if (value > 30 && value <= 40) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_3040));
                        } else if (value > 40 && value <= 50) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_4050));
                        } else if (value > 50 && value <= 60) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_5060));
                        } else if (value > 60 && value <= 70) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_6070));
                        } else if (value > 70 && value <= 80) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_7080));
                        } else if (value > 80 && value <= 90) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_8090));
                        } else if (value > 90 && value <= 100) {
                            ((ProgressBar) view)
                                    .setProgressDrawable(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.progress_90100));
                        }

                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });

            lvReportData.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Drawable :** progress_010

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#A82222"
        android:startColor="#8E0000"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="2dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: so you are adding this progress bar dynamically.

Comment: yes, actually it is part of custom listview.

Comment: Progress bar is working fine. I am getting result as first image. Now, I want to set default background which is different from setProgress. you can see it in second image.

Comment: and whats the problem with a custom progress drawable?

Comment: @pskink, It is not problem. Read my post properly.

Comment: post your Custom Drawable that you set to your Progress bar

Comment: @SimplePlan, check updated post for some code.

Comment: @JeetenParmar i got but i am talk in about this `progress_010` any one of them

Comment: @SimplePlan, It is drawable file for linear shape color.

Comment: why are you using those R.drawable.progress_XXXX ? you should use one drawable, not 10

Comment: @JeetenParmar so why 10 drawables ?

Answer (score 1):

try this Drawable like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <!-- Define background color gradient -->
  <item android:id="@android:id/background">
     <shape>
           <gradient
              android:angle="90"
              android:centerColor="#cccccc"
              android:centerY="1.0"
              android:endColor="#bbbbbb"
              android:startColor="#dddddd" />
     </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- Define progress bar color gradient -->
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
     <clip>
           <shape>
              <gradient
                 android:angle="270"
                 android:centerColor="#b4ad9e"
                 android:centerY="1.0"
                 android:endColor="#867961"
                 android:startColor="#e6d6bd" />
           </shape>
     </clip>
  </item>
```

Also create **Theme** `res/values/styles.xml`

```
 <style name="ProgressBar.Horizontal.Indeterminate" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
     <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
     <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
     <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
  </style>
```

And set to your progress bar like

```
    <ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
     style="@style/ProgressBar.Horizontal.Indeterminate"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:max="100"
     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
     android:paddingRight="20dp"
     android:paddingTop="30dp" />
```

let me know. off course in this you can change the gradient Color as per you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

Or use custom `@drawable`.

Create **my_progress.xml** in drawable folder and use color code like `#000000`.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- background line-->
  <item android:id="@android:id/background">
      <shape>
          <gradient
              android:startColor="" 
              android:centerColor="" 
              android:centerY="1.0" 
              android:endColor="" 
              android:angle="270" 
              />
      </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- status line -->
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
      <clip>
          <shape>
              <gradient
                  android:startColor="" 
                  android:centerColor="" 
                  android:centerY="1.0" 
                  android:endColor="" 
                  android:angle="270" 
                  />
          </shape>
      </clip>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

In your layout xml you need to type:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="385dp" 
        android:layout_height="160dp" 
        style="android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" 
        android:id="+id/progressBar" 
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/my_progress" 
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:max="100" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```